# Web scraped string can't be called outside the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, output

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import pandas as pd
    import requests   


    url = 'http://ips.alliance-pipeline.com/Ips/MainPage.aspx?siteCd=ALLUSA-IPS&contentSysCd=USA-OP-AVAIL-BY-DAY&tvPath=55/112/56'
    response = requets.get(url)
    html = soup(response.context, 'html.parser')

    loc = html.find_all('td', class_= 'ig162a1706')
    tsq = html.find_all('td', class_ = 'ig162a170e')

    for r in html.find_all('td', class_ = 'ig162a1706'):
        loc = r.text
        print(loc)

    for a in html.find_all('td', class_ = 'ig162a170e'):
        tsq = a.text
        print(tsq)
```

output:

```
ALLIANCE/ANR
ALLIANCE/ROSHOLT
AUX SABLE
BANTRY
BORDER USA
GUARDIAN
HANKINSON
HORIZON
LYLE
MIDWESTERN GAS TRANSMISSION
MILNOR
NATURAL GAS PIPELINE COMPANY OF AMERICA
NICOR/MORRIS
PEOPLES/ELWOOD
TIOGA
VECTOR PIPELINE
729,192
2,600
245,000
141,021
1,402,129
2,158
9,030
0
8,000
0
350
114,618
236,385
34,426
111,235
152,612
```

Error:

```
    print(loc)
```

output:

```
'VECTOR PIPELINE'
```

Hi all, basically whenever I do print(loc) outside of the for loop, it only prints `'vector pipeline'` and I'm confused as to why this is happening. Shouldn't it print the entire loop even when I execute the command outside instead of just 'vector pipeline'? Don't know what I'm doing wrong. The output is a string.

Comment: When you are assiging loc = r.text you are replacing the output of findAll() with a the value of r.text which is a string. So you are getting only one output. If you want to save the values use a list and keep appending the r.text values to the list, then outside the loop you can access your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use builtin method `zip()` and "tie" information about name and TSQ together.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://ips.alliance-pipeline.com/Ips/MainPage.aspx?siteCd=ALLUSA-IPS&contentSysCd=USA-OP-AVAIL-BY-DAY&tvPath=55/112/56'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

col1 = soup.select('td.ig162a1706')
col2 = soup.select('td.ig162a170e')

all_data = {}
for name, tsq in zip(col1, col2):
    all_data[name.text] = tsq.text

# pretty print to screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(all_data)
```

Prints:

```
{'ALLIANCE/ANR': '719,055',
 'ALLIANCE/ROSHOLT': '2,600',
 'AUX SABLE': '245,000',
 'BANTRY': '141,021',
 'BORDER USA': '1,402,129',
 'GUARDIAN': '0',
 'HANKINSON': '9,030',
 'HORIZON': '0',
 'LYLE': '8,000',
 'MIDWESTERN GAS TRANSMISSION': '0',
 'MILNOR': '350',
 'NATURAL GAS PIPELINE COMPANY OF AMERICA': '114,618',
 'NICOR/MORRIS': '236,949',
 'PEOPLES/ELWOOD': '34,426',
 'TIOGA': '111,235',
 'VECTOR PIPELINE': '173,570'}
```

---

Then you can print information about locations separately, for example:

```
# print information only for 'TIOGA'
print(all_data['TIOGA'])
```

Prints:

```
111,235
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much Andrej. Much appreciated, I was unaware of how to use the zip command and how to store the output in a list format. Thank you.